# Unity - Incorrect number of arguments to numeric-type constructor

Tags: unity-game-engine, constructor, arguments, shader

I managed to fix my previous errors, but now I spotted another two errors.

> Shader error in 'Game/Distortion (Two-sided)': incorrect number of
>   arguments to numeric-type constructor at line 179 (on d3d11)
>
> Compiling Vertex program Platform defines:
>   UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1
>   UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING
>   SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA

**In code:**

```
        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {   
            // Screen space texture coordinates
            float2 screenPos = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
            screenPos = screenPos * 0.5 + 0.5;
            screenPos.y = 1.0 - screenPos.y;

            // Time-based movement
            screenPos = screenPos * float2(4.0, 12.0) + float2(_Time.w * 3.0);

            half4 col = _Color * (0.25 * tex2D(_MainTex, screenPos).b + 0.5);
            col.a *= i.screenPos.z;
            return col;
        }
```

**At line:**

```
screenPos = screenPos * float2(4.0, 12.0) + float2(_Time.w * 3.0);
```

**And another one:**

> Shader error in 'Game/Distortion (One-sided)': incorrect number of
>   arguments to numeric-type constructor at line 179 (on d3d11)
>
> Compiling Vertex program Platform defines:
>   UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1
>   UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING
>   SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA

**In code:**

```
        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {   
            // Screen space texture coordinates
            float2 screenPos = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
            screenPos = screenPos * 0.5 + 0.5;
            screenPos.y = 1.0 - screenPos.y;

            // Time-based movement
            screenPos = screenPos * float2(4.0, 12.0) + float2(_Time.w * 3.0);

            half4 col = _Color * (0.25 * tex2D(_MainTex, screenPos).b + 0.5);
            col.a *= i.screenPos.z;
            return col;
        }
```

**At line:**

```
screenPos = screenPos * float2(4.0, 12.0) + float2(_Time.w * 3.0);
```

Same errors, actually.
Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating float2, it needs 2 values, you are currently giving just 1 float at:

```
float2(_Time.w * 3.0);
```

not sure what values you want to place there, so try with 1

```
float2(_Time.w * 3.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Or possibly `float2(_Time.w * 3.0, _Time.w * 3.0);`